# Numpy roots function and pyplot plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot the two solutions of quadratic equation as a function of a parameter ( function coeff(t) ). I am using function numpy.roots (I am sure that all roots are real in this case), and I am trying to invoke it from within pyplot.plot as below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = 3.74
def coeff(pp):
    return np.array([pp-1,r+1-0.5*pp,-r])

def sroot(t):
    return np.roots(coeff(t))

a = np.linspace(0,0.9,100)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(a,sroot(a)[0,:])
plt.plot(a,sroot(a)[1,:])

plt.show()
```

I get error message:

```
  File "quest.py", line 18, in <module>
    plt.plot(a,sroot(a)[0,:])
  File "quest.py", line 10, in sroot
    return np.roots(coeff(t))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 218, in roots
    p = p.astype(float)
```

I understand that the numpy.roots takes only list of parameters and is unable to recognize a row in array 3xlen(a). Is there a way to do it in one line, preferably inside the pyplot.plot? I would like to avoid using loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you transform all of your coefficient at once and try to call the numpy roots solver on all of them. `np.roots` only accept 1-d array and solves a single polynomial. Here is a script that does what you want:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters
r = 3.74
T = np.linspace(0.0,0.9,100)

# Coefficients
C = np.zeros((len(T),3))
C[:,0] = T-1
C[:,1] = r + 1 - 0.5*T
C[:,2] = r

# Roots
R = np.zeros((len(T),2))
for i in range(len(T)):
    R[i] = np.roots(C[i])

# Plot
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(T,R[:,0])
plt.plot(T,R[:,1])

plt.show()
```

Comment: I always thought python to be an elegant language, so I was looking for solutions that are shorter and do not have any for-loops. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes. Because you've have only second order polynomials, you can directly find the roots (i.e. without using `np.roots`).